# Can not access admin panel while configuring Keycloak 22.0 running under ngnix reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a situation in which I run **Keycloak 22.0** behind the Nginx reverse proxy. It works fine if I configure the Nginx config file under **/**; however, If I try to configure it under, for example, ***/sso***, I can not access the admin page. Below is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data:


services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassssss
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0
    command: start-dev
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: mypassssss
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ad123456
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: password
      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: 'false'
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: 'true'
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: secret
      KC_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      KC_PROXY: edge
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  nginx-svc:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - keycloak
```

And the working version of Nginx config:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080/;
    }
}
```

Then, If I hit http://localhost in the browser, it works fine.

If I change my Nginx config to:

```
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /sso/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080/;
    }
}
```

I can see the user interface but can not access the admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change `KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH` if you want keycloak to be hosted in a sub path.

Add `KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH: /sso` in your keycloak environment should fix the issue.

documents: https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config?q=relative

Comment: Hi @jsxqf 

Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, it does not work. If I add the relative path, it shows resources not found.

Comment: @SMFarhadAli turns out you also need to update the nginx config a bit: remove the end `/` in proxy_pass section.

Comment: Hi @jsxqf 

Thanks, it worked!